# Remove duplicates column on Max nan value

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe with duplicate headers. Some duplicate headers have `nan` value that I want to delete and retain the max numeric col in the dataframe.

Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wlxDLhBdjwUJUefreXJz5s-vnYGTVf0g/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=109006474326015950766&rtpof=true&sd=true) to the dataframe file (it's an Excel file)

I tried the below but did not achieve my goal.

[image: original dataframe]

required output as below:
[image: Required dataframe]

Comment: i tried above approach but not able to got my gole,any one please suggest